# Web-based project planning and task management system with resource leveling

Tags: project-management

At work, I'm currently using:

- Microsoft Project (to plan task order and project deadlines)
- Trello (to keep visible track of what tasks are in progress, and what tasks are up next)
- Redmine (for version control integration, and task-specific information and communication)

I'm looking for a single tool to replace those. Features I want:

Must haves:

- Gantt chart, to show the project plan
- Web-based, so that the project plan is always visible
- Fine-grained control over task priority (which Redmine doesn't have)
- Automatic resource-leveling, based on task priority

Nice-to-haves:

- A kanban "these are my assigned tasks" view
- Subversion integration

Comment: I haven't used it, but I believe [FogBugz](http://www.fogcreek.com/fogbugz/) (same authors as Trello) should have the features. It's not free though (but neither is MS Project). I would also be interested in other alternatives, especially free ones (we are bit tight on the budget, so it would definitely be easier to get approved), but I've not heard of any yet.

Comment: I just had a look at another tool based on my search for task management software via stack exchange. I found [proofhub.com](http://www.proofhub.com) in another answer on this stack.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still looking for a similar solution, I would recommend [Teamhood](https://teamhood.com/use-cases/task-management/). It fits all the requirements and is free for up to 5 users.

If you would like to see more options, here is a comparison of the best [task management tools](https://teamhood.com/project-management/task-management-tools/) out there.